# how to get the input - strong and p elements on the same line?

Tags: css, css-float

I have the following html content.

```
      <div><input type="checkbox"><strong></strong><p></p></div>
```

How do I get these elements on the same line with the p element with no-wrap?

I tried this:

```
input
{
   float: left;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}

strong
{
   float: left;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
p
{
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   white-space: nowrap;
}
```

What I don't understand about this css setting is that the p element takes up the entire width of the div element. For example, the div width is 1360 and the p element is also 1360 but yet the strong width is 184 and the input width is 16 and they all fit on the same line with the p element overflowing on the horizontal line.

Comment: You forgot to add html content to question

Comment: the problem remains after fixing overflow value to left value and pushing the html content 4 spaces to the right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you give the `<p>` a `float:left;`, you must give the `<div>` a `overflow:hidden;`.

And if you would like to lower the `<input>` a little bit, then give it a `margin-top`.

Check this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/AliBassam/Ygs7j/).

**CSS**

```
div
{
    overflow:hidden;
}
input
{
   float: left;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}

strong
{
   float: left;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
p
{
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
    float:left;
   white-space: nowrap;
}
```

The reason why `<p>` takes the full width, it's because the `display` property of `<p>` is `block`, just like `<div>`, it will take full width unless you float it.

Answer (score 0):

float: overflow; doesn't exists, it can only be left or right.

Answer (score 0):

You need to float the p left.  Floating everything left will snap them all on the same line (as long as the positioning is relative, which you should do as well)

```
p{
float: left;
position: relative;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

always use display:inline to put elements on a line:

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <strong>Hello</strong>
    <p>World</p>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
input{
   float: overflow;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}

strong
{
   float: overflow;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
p
{
   display:inline; 
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   white-space: nowrap;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bpze6/1/